# Foreach List with unknown item type

Tags: c#

I need to go through List. I do not know in advance what type of element List contains the List I get as an object.

```
void anyMethod(object listData, Func<object, string> callback)
{
    foreach (object item in (List<object>)data)
    {
        string value = callback(item);
        doSomething(value)
    }
};
...
List<MyObject> myList = something();
anyMethod(myList, obj => (MyObject)obj.Name)
...
List<AnotherObject> myList = somethingAnother();
anyMethod(myList, obj => (AnotherObject)obj.foo + (AnotherObject)obj.bar)
...
```

I need something he does as DropDownList when the process DataSource.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for generics, to me.

Comment: There is a typo, with `listData` and `data`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this:

```
void anyMethod(object listData, Func<object, string> callback)
{
    IEnumerable enumerable = listData as IEnumerable;
    if(enumerable == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("listData mist be enumerable");
    foreach (object item in enumerable.OfType<object>())
    {
        string value = callback(item);
        doSomething(value)
    }
};
```

However, if you actually call this method with a strongly typed list (such as `List<YourType>`) you can use generics better:

```
void anyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> listData, Func<T, string> callback)
{
    foreach (T item in listData)
    {
        string value = callback(item);
        doSomething(value)
    }
};
```

which is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

If `DoSomething()` is a static method, you can use a generic extension method (as `List<T>` itself is generic anyway):

```
public static void AnyMethod<T>(this List<T> listData, Func<T, string> callback)
{
    foreach (T item in listData)
    {
        string value = callback(item);
        DoSomething(value);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
List<MyObject> myList = Something();
myList.AnyMethod(obj => obj.Name);

List<AnotherObject> myList = SomethingAnother();
myList.AnyMethod(obj => obj.foo + obj.bar);
```

Notice you do not need to cast either.

However, if `DoSomething()` is an instance method, I think you can go with [Jamiec's second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953116/foreach-list-with-unknown-item-type/6953150#6953150).

Comment: +1 for making it an extension method in addition to using generics.  Nicely done :)

Comment: Per .NET naming conventions, you should also use PascalCase for your method names (as I do in my answer).